# Check if node net socket has work in progress

Tags: node.js, sockets

Is there a possibility to check if a [net](https://www.npmjs.com/package/net) socket is currently working (i.e.: actively sending or receiving data)? 
I checked the [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html), but I couldn't find anything related.

In my case, I have an open socket between a socket client and the node server. When a HTTP client makes a request, the server communicates under the hood with the socket client.

The problem is that if `list-files` is currently in progress and I request `rename-file`, the operation is blocked by the first request. My solution is to have multiple open sockets between node server and socket client, in order to parallelise requests.

In order to know which socket I can use for a request, I need to know if it is idle or working already on another request (e.g.: especially when a file download/upload is in progress).

```
var clientSockets = []

router.post('/list-files', function(req, res) {
    var clientSockets = clientSockets.filter(function(currSocket) {
        return currSocket.userID === "user1@example.com"
    })

    // What should I do here?
    // var availableClientSocket = clientSockets.filter(

    writeMessageToSocket(availableClientSocket, socketReq.fromHttpReq(req))
    readMessageFromSocket(availableClientSocket, socketRes)

    res.write(socketRes)
}

router.post('/rename-file', function(req, res) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could give every socket an ID and add an array `workingSockets`:

```
var clientSockets = []
var workingSockets = []

router.post('/list-files', function(req, res) {
    var availableSocket;
    for(var i = 0; i < clientSockets.length; i++) {
        for(var k = 0; k < workingSockets.length; k++) {
            if(workingSockets[k] === clientSockets[i].id) return
        }
        if(clientSockets[i].socket.userID === "user1@example.com") availableSocket = clientSockets[i]
    }

    writeMessageToSocket(availableClientSocket.socket, socketReq.fromHttpReq(req))
    readMessageFromSocket(availableClientSocket.socket, socketRes)

    res.write(socketRes)

    workingSockets.splice(workingSockets.indexOf(availableSocket.id), 1)
}

router.post('/rename-file', function(req, res) {
    // ...
}
```

Now, you need to rewrite your code a bit: Your `clientSockets` now is an array containing JSON Objects:

```
var object = {
    id: '123', // You need a unique ID for every socket. It's very important that there
               // exists exactly one socket with that ID. Otherwise, the code breaks.
    socket: new net.Socket(...)
}
```

Comment: I understand I can manually do the logic, but I am asking about an official, reliable solution.

Comment: You could try making use of the `end` event of the socket. https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_class_net_socket